# Syncfusion's Masked Edit keeps on appending the old value to the new value even after I create a new instance

Tags: c#, regex, wpf, syncfusion

I've encountered a weird interaction with Syncfusion's Masked Edit, it's a 3rd party WPF control that's basically a text box that takes a string mask and lets you choose how you'd want to interpret it (the one I currently set it to is RegEx) to filter out your text.

After creating a new `NewCustomer` through my Reset Command, if I try to type on a Masked Edit that had a value before creating the new instance it somehow still remembers that old value and appends it to the new value. Here's a clip of it (https://gfycat.com/embellishedpalefantail)

**What I've tried:**

I've tried removing the `Mask` and `MaskType` properties and ran the program to see if there was something else causing it but since it ran fine, the problem seems to lie on the Mask itself,

1. Could it be that they interpret my mask differently and it's behaving how they wanted it to?
2. Or is my Mask simply just wrong and it's interpreting it normally? Because with my mask of `[0-9a-zA-Z ]{0,20}`, I expected it to only allow alphanumeric characters and a space with a minimum length of 0 and maximum length of 20.

**Here's a code of everything that's involved with my problem:**

**C#**

1. The property the Text Value is bound to:

   ```
   private Customer newCustomer;
   public Customer NewCustomer
   {
       get { return newCustomer; }
       set { newCustomer = value; RaisePropertyChanged("NewCustomer"); }
   }

   public class Customer : BaseSearchableCollectionClass
   {
       private string firstName;
       public string FirstName
       {
           get { return firstName; }
           set { firstName = value; RaisePropertyChanged("FirstName"); }
       }
   }

   // The BaseSearchableCollectionClass contains the INotify implementation and other unrelated code
   ```
2. The reset command:

   ```
   public RelayCommand ResetNewCustomerCommand { get; private set; }
   public void ResetNewCustomer(object msg)
   {
       NewCustomer = new Customer();
   }
   public bool ResetNewCustomerCanUse(object msg)
   {
       if (HasChange() == true)
           return true;
       return false;
   }
   ```

**XAML**

1. SFMaskedEdit:

   ```
   <chart:SfMaskedEdit
       Text="{Binding NewCustomer.FirstName, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"                          
       Mask="[0-9a-zA-Z ]{0,20}" 
       MaskType="RegEx"
    />
   ```
2. Reset Button:

   ```
    <Button 
       Command="{Binding ResetNewCustomerCommand}" 
       Content="Reset"
    />
   ```

**What I expected:**

I expected it to run exactly like this:

1. I type something on the Masked Edit
2. Masked Edit filters out any unwanted characters and maintains length requirements
3. I press the reset button to create a New Customer, effectively clearing out any existing values
4. I type a new value on the Masked Edit as if it were a new text box (Unfortunately the problem lies here where it appends the cleared value to the new value)

Comment: Oh and the red border isn't from a validation error, I simply just set the border brush to red so I can color code the controls with a problem.

Answer (score 1):

The reported case is an defect with SfMaskedEdit control and we will include fix for issue in our upcoming release.

Regards,
Magesh S